# 300Mbps wireless router but extremely slow speeds

Tags: router, connection, speed, wifi-transfer

I have a TP-Link TL-WR840N (which claims to be a b/g/n 300Mbps WiFi router) connected to Wimax modem and to a PC using one gigabit port. When I send or receive files from other devices (Android smartphones, tablets - all b/g/n) it gives me a terrible speed that never exceeds 1Mbps no matter the method used (FTP, SMB, or HTTP).

Is this normal? If not I will need to take it to the service center.

Comment: even when sending files between my phones gives me 700 kb/s!

Comment: That also could be an issue because of you neighbor networks. If someone else is nearly close to your channel, the bandwidth decrease pretty strong. Optimal channel resolution for near field communication is 1, 4, 8, 12. So if your have more then 3 other networks in your area, you have to expect, that you lose some bandwidth.

Comment: mine is on channel 11 and there isn't any other network on this channel.

Comment: what is the next channel near to your?

Comment: even if you are the only one on channel 11, someone on channel 10 or 12 may disturb your connection. Nobody know, but to have a full bandwidth you router need more then one channel.

Answer (score -2):

Go look in your security settings on the router and change it from WPA to WEP2, re-enter your setting (name, passkey, ect) and reboot.

Comment: Can you give more detail to this answer. Why will doing this help the OP with the problem? Thanks

Comment: I'ts already WEP2.

Comment: This is a very bad advice. WEP is inherently insecure and should not be used.